# What does mean <version>#{site.components['arquillian-core'].latest_version}</version> in Maven?

Tags: maven, jboss-arquillian

I'm learning a little bit about [Arquillian](http://arquillian.org) and in [this guide](http://arquillian.org/guides/getting_started/?utm_source=cta) has the following code snipet:

```
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian</groupId>
            <artifactId>arquillian-bom</artifactId>
            <version>#{site.components['arquillian-core'].latest_version}</version>
            <scope>import</scope>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

but I don't know how to interpret this dependency, in particular the `<version>` line, can anyone shed some light on the matter? My questions are: what is the version EL expression? and what is a `bom` package? (I read that it stands for Build Of Materials, but I don't know what it is).

Thanks in advance for your answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anyone else who is stuck should check [the solution provided by the dev in response to the OP here.](https://developer.jboss.org/thread/272918)

TL; DR: it's a mistake in the tutorial, the version should be:

```
<version>1.1.11.Final</version>
```

Comment: Thanks for completing this question. Indeed, I asked that question in the Jboss Developer forum and it turned to be a mistake in the document generation. Thanks again for your time.